# Control Trigger in SQL Developer compiling but not working

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to use a trigger that checks if a user can be a added to the table depending on it's age. If the birth Date is less than 13 it should throw an error.
The thing is, it compiles correctly but it is not working.

The pk of the Users_table is username.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGECONTROL
BEFORE INSERT ON Users_table
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,:new.birthdate)/12) < 12 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Minimal age is 13.');
    END IF;
END;
```

Ps. I have tried using the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGECONTROL
BEFORE INSERT ON Users_table
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    birthDateUser DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT u.birthDate INTO birthDateUser FROM Users_table u WHERE :new.username = u.username
  IF TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,:new.birthdate)/12) < 12 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Minimal age is 13.');
    END IF;
END;
```

But as the table User u does not exist it throws an error.

Thanks!

Comment: `IF TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,:new.birthdate)/12) < 12 THEN` should be `<=` rather than `<` (or `12` should be `13`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGECONTROL
  BEFORE INSERT ON Users_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), :new.birthdate) < 12 * 13
  THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Minimal age is 13.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d1313a9cc927cdde8871093806216797)*